# Working Week Completion

Tags: code-golf, number, date

I work a standard nine to five. Monday through Friday. I take a half hour for lunch from 12:30 to 13:00.

Write me a program which, when run, calculates the percentage of the working week that I have completed at the current moment.

Rules

- Only count time actually spent working. I am punctual and do not work
  over lunch.
- No input. You may obtain information like current time/date however is convenient.
- The working week is considered complete from end-of-day Friday to midnight between Sunday and Monday.
- Timezone is the local timezone.
- Output should be a decimal number, eg 66.25498, percentage symbol optional.
- The program should be reasonably future-proof. It should be able to cope with leap years.
- Output resolution should be a second or better. I like to watch the kettle boil.
- Code golf. Shortest code wins.

Comment: What's your time zone? System local? GMT? Oh, and is that midnight between Saturday and Sunday or Sunday and Monday?

Comment: I updated the rules. Local time, and the Sunday/Monday midnight.

Comment: Are you earning wages during lunch break?

Comment: I don't think that would make a difference?

Comment: if you are at lunch, you are not working, therefore, I guessed at a 37.5 hour work week

Comment: Given Fraxtil's solution, I'd like to ask for an official clarification on the minimum acceptable time resolution.

Comment: I think time resolution should really be a second or better. I'll amend the rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Q, <strike>111</strike> 102

```
0|100*("i"$(27000000*((.z.d)mod 7)-2)+{0|((17:00:00&x)-09:00:00)-0|00:30:00&x-12:30:00}.z.t)%135000000
```

Answer (score 5):

### Python 3, 132

```
from datetime import*
t=datetime.now().timetuple()
m=max(0,t[3]*2+t[4]/30-18)
print(20*min(5,(t[6]+min(15,m-min(8,max(7,m))+7)/15)))
```

The resolution is one minute, or 2/45 of a percent. That's more than enough IMO.

Answer (score 5):

### Excel, <strike>132</strike>, <strike>129</strike>, <strike>123</strike>,<strike>119</strike>, 117

paste into A2:A4

```
=NOW()
=A2-INT(A2)-.375
=(WEEKDAY(A2,3)*7.5+IF(A3<0,0,IF(A3>TIME(8,0,0),7.5,(A3-IF(A3>.1875,TIME(0,30,0),0))*24)))/37.5
```

format the cell A4 as % to get the correct format

40 hour workweek-Paid lunch:

### <strike>88</strike>, 81

```
=NOW()
=A1-INT(A1)-.375
=(WEEKDAY(A1,3)*8+IF(A2<0,0,IF(A2>TIME(8,0,0),8,A2*24)))/40
```

Comment: The first does not appear to work when `NOW()` is a time after 5PM.

Comment: augh - a *24 in the wrong position.....

Comment: :-) BTW, good job besting me at my VBA approach using formulas instead. Now I'm nitpicking... Your update added a char (`0`) that isn't necessary!

Comment: my excuse is I haven't been at work after 5:00 for quite a while :D

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 124 chars

OK, simple first solution to set the par:

```
say(($p=((($s,$m,$h,@t)=localtime)[6]+6)%7*20+(($h+=$m/60+$s/3600-9)<0?0:$h<3.5?$h:$h<4?3.5:$h<8?$h-.5:7.5)*8/3)<100?$p:100)
```

Run with `perl -M5.010` to enable the Perl 5.10+ `say` feature.  Resolution is one second; if one minute resolution is acceptable, the `+$s/3600` part can be deleted for a total length of **116 chars**.

This solution uses `localtime` to get the day of week and the time of day, so it should work regardless of year changes, leap days or any other calendar peculiarities, at least as long as the seven day week cycle doesn't change.  DST changes during the workday would slightly confuse it, but those basically never happen anyway, presumably precisely because that would lead to way too much confusion.

(For testing convenience, note that `localtime` accepts a Unix timestamp as an optional argument.)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica  <strike>169 168 212 214 211 218 210</strike> 190 chars

Long-winded, by code golf Standards.

The following takes into account working weeks crossing month or year boundaries, as well as leap years.  It reckons time worked according to hours and minutes.

I couldn't think of a way to avoid spelling out the days of the week.  Mathematica returns day of week as a 3 character string, which has to be converted to a number.

```
h = Plus @@ {#1, #2/60, #3/3600} & @@ Take[DateList[], -3]; 100*Min[37.5, (StringTake[DateString[], 3] /. {"Mon" -> 0, "Tue" -> 1, "Wed" -> 2 , "Thu" -> 3, "Fri" -> 4, _ -> 5})*7.5 + Which[h < 12.5, Max[0, h - 9], h < 13, 4, True, 4 + Min[h - 13, 4]]]/37.5
```

---

**De-golfed**

```
(* d returns {year, mo, day, h, m, s}   *)
d = DateList[]

(* finished Days: hours worked *)
f = (StringTake[DateString[],  3] /. {"Mon" -> 0, "Tue" -> 1, "Wed" -> 2 , "Thu" -> 3, "Fri" -> 4, _ -> 5})*7.5

(* time of day in hours *)
h = Plus @@ {#1, #2/60} & @@ Take[d, -3]

(* today: hours Worked. It also computes hours for Sat and Sunday but does not use 
them in the final tabulation, which has a maximum of 37.5. *)
t = Which[h < 12.5, Max[0, h - 9], h < 13, 4, _, 4 + Min[h - 13, 4]]

(* hours Worked in week *)
tot = Min[37.5, f + t]

(* % of working week completed *)
100*tot/37.5
```

[image: work week]

Answer (score 2):

### VBA 141

Formatted to run from the immediate window. Thanks to [Sean Cheshire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/5011/sean-cheshire) for pointing out a 10-char improvement!

```
n=(Now-Int(Now))*24:a=(Weekday(Now,3)*7.5+IIf(n>17,7.5,IIf(n>9,IIf(n<12.5,n,IIf‌​(n>13,n-.5,n))-9,0)))/37.5:MsgBox Format(IIf(a>1,1,a),".0%")
```

Comment: use n=n*24, and it can be reduced more. my fight with it produced this: `n=(Now-Int(Now))*24:a=(Weekday(Now,3)*7.5+IIf(n>17,7.5,IIf(n>9,IIf(n<12.5,n,IIf(n>13,n-.5,n))-9,0)))/37.5:MsgBox Format(IIf(a>1,1,a),".0%")` @ 139

Comment: @SeanCheshire Excellent point! My method had some left-over syntax from an earlier version that used n, so it couldn't be modified.

Answer (score 1):

### R, 115 chars

```
---------1---------2---------3---------4---------5---------6---------7---------8---------9---------0---------1---------2
T=as.POSIXlt(Sys.time()-86400);z=T$h+T$mi/60-9;D=function(x,M)min(M,max(0,x));D(((D(z,8)-D(z-3.5,.5))/7.5+T$w)/5,1)
```

Here is a one-week simulation:

```
week.frac <- function(t) {
   T <- as.POSIXlt(t-86400)
   z <- T$h+T$mi/60-9
   D <- function(x,M)min(M,max(0,x))
   D(((D(z,8)-D(z-3.5,.5))/7.5+T$w)/5,1)
}

time <- seq(from = as.POSIXlt(as.Date("2012-08-20")),
            to   = as.POSIXlt(as.Date("2012-08-27")),
            by   = "min")
week.completion <- sapply(time, week.frac)
plot(time, week.completion, type = "l")
```

[image: week completion for current week]

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, <strike>191</strike> <strike>116,115</strike> 113

The logic is stolen from Fraxtils [Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7011/5183).

```
t=Time.now
d=t.wday
m=[0,t.hour*2+t.min/3e1-18].max
p d<1?100:20*[5,(d-1+[15,m-[8,[7,m].max].min+7].min/15)].min
```

If you want to test the code with the unit test, you need this 143 character solution:

```
class Time  
def r
m=[0,hour*2+min/3e1-18].max
d=wday
d<1?100:20*[5,(d-1+[15,m-[8,[7,m].max].min+7].min/15)].min
end    
end
p Time.now.r
```

---

Not the shortest and most efficient code, but with a unit test ;)

The 191 characters include the newlines (I could make it a one-liner, just replace each newline with a `;`).

```
class Time
def r
i=0
d{|t|i+=t.w}
i/1350.0
end
def d
t=dup
yield t-=1 until t.strftime('%w%T')=='109:00:00'
end
def w
h=hour
wday<1||wday>5||h<9||h>16||h==12&&min>29?0:1
end
end
p Time.now.r
```

And the testcode:

```
require 'test/unit'
class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_mo
    assert_equal( 20, Time.new(2012,8,13,20).r) #monday
  end
  def test_tue
    assert_equal( 40, Time.new(2012,8,14,20).r) #tuesday
  end
  def test_wed_morning
    assert_equal( 40, Time.new(2012,8,15,7).r)
  end
  def test_wed
    assert_equal( 60, Time.new(2012,8,15,20).r)
  end
  def test_thu
    assert_equal( 80, Time.new(2012,8,16,20).r)
  end
  def test_fri
    assert_equal(100, Time.new(2012,8,17,20).r)
  end
  def test_sat
    assert_equal(100, Time.new(2012,8,18,20).r)
  end
  def test_sun
    assert_equal(100, Time.new(2012,8,19,20).r)
  end
  def test_middle
    assert_equal(50, Time.new(2012,8,15,13,15).r)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2  130 chars

```
from datetime import*
t=datetime.now().timetuple();
m=min
a=max
n=t[3]+t[4]/60.0
print m(17,a(9,n))-9-(a(0,m(.5,n-12.5)))+7.5*m(t[6],4)
```

Meh third attempt is weak sauce but I think I've gotten the logic right.

Comment: This doesn't work. At a quick glance of the output, there are no long periods of time where the percentage remains the same, which should be the case between each day's 5:00 PM to the following day's 9:00 AM, as well as each 12:30-1:00 PM interval. It also outputs negative numbers and numbers greater than 100 at times.

Comment: Oh, shame on me. You're absolutely right. Mulligan.

Comment: @Fraxtil I think I've edged you out by a hair

Comment: This appears to have a range of 0 to 37.5. It does pause during the appropriate intervals, though.

Comment: Oh I had it set to print out the number of hours for debugging. I forgot to change it over to % for answer. I'm guessing I won't be able to do that in 2 characters so I guess you got me after all

Comment: After `from datetime import*` you can simply use `now()`. And `a=max` is not economic (and `m=min` is useless).

Comment: @ugoren, your first point is incorrect. The full path to the method is `datetime.datetime.now()`.

Comment: Am I miscounting or are we to count line returns/newlines as well? a=max is 4 char; I use max twice so you're right, that one's a wash but m=min is a saver because I call min() 3 times

Comment: @Fraxtil, I guess you're right, though I can't guess why it would be done so. Regarding newlines - all whitespace which can't be removed must be counted. You can't erase newlines here (without adding `;`) so you have to count them.

Comment: @ugoren the `datetime` package also contains `date` and `time` classes so `datetime.datetime...` is needed to differentiate between them.

Comment: @ugoren also, is there a preferred way to count chars for codegolfing? I threw it into Word and went with their char count (for shame...) which appears to ignore non-printing characters in its character count.

Comment: @IamChuckB, I don't know a good method. Linux's `wc` can work, or you can marge all to one line (spaces instead of newlines) and use Notepad which shows the column number.