# Plug it back in tonight or this weekend

Tags: code-golf, date

*This is my first code golf so please let me know if it's too broad or if I'm missing any information for a good puzzle!*

## Challenge

In Ontario and possibly other areas of the world, electricity is billed using [Time-Of-Use (TOU) pricing](https://hydroottawa.com/residential/time-of-use/rate-periods/), which varies the cost per kilowatt-hour according to when you use power.

Given a date and time, I want to know whether I'm in an on-peak (red), mid-peak (yellow), or off-peak (green) time period.

## Input

Assume that input is provided in an acceptable timezone-less [ISO 8601 date-time format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) with the minimum precision of hours: `YYYY-MM-DDThh[:mm[:ss]]` (the T is literal).

#### Examples

- 2014-09-01T14
- 2014-09-01T17:30
- 2014-09-01T17:30:02

## Output

The output should be a string `On`, `Mid`, or `Off`.

## Rules

- Shortest code wins
- For the purposes of this challenge, ignore statutory holidays
- Assume the information found in this post. The actual rules of time-of-use pricing might change in the future by the Ontario Ministry of Energy.

## Information

### Summer weekdays (May 1st to October 31st)

[image: Time-of-use clock for summer weekdays]

- Off-peak: 19h00 - 07h00
- Mid-peak: 07h00 - 11h00 and 17h00 - 19h00
- On-peak: 11h00 - 17h00

### Winter weekdays (November 1st to April 30th)

[image: Time-of-use clock for winter weekdays]

- Off-peak: 19h00 - 07h00
- Mid-peak: 11h00 - 17h00
- On-peak: 07h00 - 11h00 and 17h00 - 19h00

### Weekends

[image: Time-of-use clock on weekends]

- Off-peak: All day

Comment: Are you sure the winter weekdays don't have mid-peak / on-peak swapped?

Comment: @JanDvorak, in winter people use lights and heating in the morning and evening; in summer they use air-con at midday.

Comment: This is borderline-duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7008/194 (parse a datetime and do a simple calculation based on whether it's a working day or not). I think the season dependency is just different enough, but others may disagree.

Comment: @PeterTaylor the rules seem much simpler here than in the linked question. This doesn't have to handle leap years, for example.

Comment: @JanDvorak you do need to consider leap years to correctly calculate the weekends in February and March. However it does seem simpler in its rules and output, and more rigid in its datetime format,  so I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: Should the general date format be `YYYY-MM-DDThh[:mm[:ss]]` since seconds can only be applied if minutes are applied?

Comment: Buy two of these, plug them in, program them, and then move the plug from one to the next twice a year. Problem solved: http://www.amazon.com/GE-Plug-In-Digital-Security-Feature/dp/B007BJUKVM unless you just want off-peak and don't care about mid peak.  Then you only need one.  If you don't care about weekends you can get a cheaper 24 hour timer.

Comment: Semi-on topic: I'm happy BC is fighting against those smart meters ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Ruby - <s>147 144 143 141 137</s> 135

```ruby
x=->s{y,m,d,h=s.scan(/\d+/).map &:to_i
g=Time.new(y,m,d).wday%6<1?0:[0..11,4..9].count{|r|r===h-7}
%W{Off Mid On}[m<5||m>10?(3-g)%3:g]}
```

This represents a function which takes a string as a parameter and returns a string.

Here's an online demo with some test cases: **http://ideone.com/wyIydw**

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2 - 164

```
from datetime import*
d,t=input().split('T')
y,m,d=map(int,d.split('-'))
t=int(t[:2])
print'OMOfinfd'[(1+((10<t<17)==(4<m<11)))*(date(y,m,d).weekday()<5<6<t<19)::3]
```

---

If needed, below is a explanation of the logic in the final line:

The final line prints a slice of `'OMOfinfd'` depending on the evaluation of its conditionals.

- First, evaluate the operation `1+((10<t<17)==(4<m<11))`.

  If the XNOR between the conditions `10<t<17` and `4<m<11` is `False`, this will evaluate to `1+False => 1+0 => 1`. Otherwise, the operation will evaluate to `1+True => 1+1 => 2`.
- Finally, multiply that result of the above operation by whether the day is a weekday and whether the time is between 6am-7pm.

  If this is `False`, either the day is a weekend or the time is between 7pm-6am, and the result will be `(1|2)*0 => 0`. Otherwise the result will be `(1|2)*1 => 1|2`.

A result of `0` will print `Off`, `1` will print `Mid`, and `2` will print `On`.

Comment: Isn't the golfed version actually longer because you use semicolons? Or are newlines counted?

Comment: Newlines are typically counted. In Notepad++ (where I typically get my counts) the ungolfed version is 4bytes longer at 168.

Comment: @BeetDemGuise Edit → EOL Conversion → UNIX/OSX Format.

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby - 135

Abuses the Time module. Input by command line argument.

```ruby
d=Time.new(*$*[0].scan(/\d+/)[0..3])
o,m,f=%w{On Mid Off}
o,m=m,o if (d.mon-5)%10<6
p d.wday%6<1||(12>h=(d.hour+5)%24)?f:15<h&&h<22?m:o
```

**Edit:** Thanks w0lf for Time which helped shorten and solve a bug.

Comment: Your program is incorrect. For the input `2014-09-01T17:30` it correctly outputs `"Mid"`, but for `2014-09-01T17` it outputs `"Off"`.

Answer (score 5):

### C# - <s>240</s> 220 chars

```c#
string x(string s){var d=DateTime.Parse((s+":00:00").Substring(0,19));int h=d.Hour,i=(int)d.DayOfWeek,x=d.Month;string o="off",m="mid",f="on";return i==6|i==0?o:x>=5&x<11?h>18|h<7?o:h>10&h<17?f:m:h>18|h<7?o:h>10&h<17?m:f;}
```

Nothing special. Straight forward coding.

Thanks to w0lf :)

Comment: I think you can shorten `s.Length==13?s+":00:00":s.Length==16?s+":00":s` to `(s+":00:00").Substring(0,19)`

Answer (score 3):

### Groovy - <strike>621</strike> <strike>534</strike> <strike>524</strike> 491 chars

Some further golfing to do, but pretty simple when leveraging Joda-Time

```
@Grab(group='joda-time',module='joda-time',version='2.3')
f={p,a->org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern(p).parseDateTime a}
g={p,a->def x=null;try{x=f p,a}catch(Exception e){}}
a=args[0]
d=["",":mm",":mm:ss"].collect{g "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH$it",a}.find{it}
r="Off"
m="Mid"
j={d,a,b->d.hourOfDay>a&&d.hourOfDay<b}
k={j(it,6,11)||(j(it,16,19))}
if(d.dayOfWeek<6){x=d.monthOfYear;if(x>4&&x<12){if(j(d,10,17))r="On";if(k(d))r=m}else if(x<5||x>10){if(j(d,10,17))r=m;if(k(d))r="On"}}
println r
```

sample runs:

```
bash-3.2$ ./run.peak.sh 
groovy Peak.groovy 2014-08-26T19
Off
groovy Peak.groovy 2014-08-26T07:00
Mid
groovy Peak.groovy 2014-08-26T18:00:00
Mid
groovy Peak.groovy 2014-08-26T12:30:30
On
groovy Peak.groovy 2014-11-01T00
Off
groovy Peak.groovy 2014-02-05T11:11:11
Mid
groovy Peak.groovy 2014-01-05T08:08
Off
groovy Peak.groovy 2014-12-18T18:59:59
On
groovy Peak.groovy 2014-08-31T14
Off
```

Ungolfed:

```
@Grab(group='joda-time',module='joda-time',version='2.3')

f = { p,a -> org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern(p).parseDateTime a}
g = { p,a -> def x=null; try{x=f p,a} catch(Exception e) {} }
a=args[0]

d = ["",":mm",":mm:ss"].collect{g "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH$it",a}.find{it}
r = "Off"
m = "Mid"

j = {d,a,b -> d.hourOfDay > a && d.hourOfDay < b}
k = { j(it,6,11) || (j(it,16,19)) }

if (d.dayOfWeek<6) {
    x = d.monthOfYear;
    if ( x>4 && x<12 ) {
        if (j(d,10,17)) r="On";
        if (k(d)) r=m
    } else if (x<5||x>10) {
        if (j(d,10,17)) r=m;
        if (k(d)) r="On"
    }
}
println r
```

Comment: Since Java 8, there's also `java.time.*`, which is very similar to Joda Time but is part of the JRE. Perhaps this could shorten the code a bit.

Comment: re: Java 8. excellent point

Comment: In your 3rd-to-last example `'2014-01-05T08:08'`, January 5th, 2014 is a Sunday. Thus, it should be `'Off'`

Comment: re: Jan 5, 2014. Quite right. The current code is correct, but the output run is wrong. Will fix.

Comment: Tried `java.time.*`. failed miserably. The parser is too damn strict. Use `DateParser` from nashorn (also part of the JRE8) which is lenient, and with a bit of abusive hacking, even lenient enough to skip minutes&seconds.

Answer (score 2):

### R, <s>243</s> 204 characters

```
b=strptime(scan(,""),"%Y-%m-%dT%H");i=function(x)as.integer(format(b,x));h=i("%H");d=i("%m%d");w=d>1100|d<430;f=ifelse;cat(c("Off","Mid","On")[f(i("%u")%in%5:6|h<7|h>19,1,f(h>11&h<17,f(w,2,3),f(w,3,2)))])
```

Indented and commented:

```r
b=strptime(scan(,""),"%Y-%m-%dT%H") #Takes stdin and converts into POSIXct
i=function(x)as.integer(format(b,x)) #Format the POSIXct and convert it to integer
h=i("%H")      #Format to hours
d=i("%m%d")    #Format to Month/Day
w=d>1100|d<430 #True if winter time, false if summer
f=ifelse
cat(c("Off","Mid","On")[f(i("%u")%in%5:6|h<7|h>19, #If weekend or night
                          1,                       #Case 1
                          f(h>11&h<17,            #Else if mid-day
                             f(w,3,2),             #Case 2 in winter, case 3 in summer
                             f(w,2,3)))])          #else vice versa
```

Examples:

```
> b=strptime(scan(,""),"%Y-%m-%dT%H");i=function(x)as.integer(format(b,x));h=i("%H");d=i("%m%d");w=d>1100|d<430;f=ifelse;cat(c("Off","Mid","On")[f(i("%u")%in%5:6|h<7|h>19,1,f(h>11&h<17,f(w,3,2),f(w,2,3)))])
1: 2014-08-26T15
2: 
Read 1 item
On
> b=strptime(scan(,""),"%Y-%m-%dT%H");i=function(x)as.integer(format(b,x));h=i("%H");d=i("%m%d");w=d>1100|d<430;f=ifelse;cat(c("Off","Mid","On")[f(i("%u")%in%5:6|h<7|h>19,1,f(h>11&h<17,f(w,3,2),f(w,2,3)))])
1: 2014-12-10T15
2: 
Read 1 item
Mid
> b=strptime(scan(,""),"%Y-%m-%dT%H");i=function(x)as.integer(format(b,x));h=i("%H");d=i("%m%d");w=d>1100|d<430;f=ifelse;cat(c("Off","Mid","On")[f(i("%u")%in%5:6|h<7|h>19,1,f(h>11&h<17,f(w,3,2),f(w,2,3)))])
1: 2014-08-26T23
2: 
Read 1 item
Off
```

Answer (score 1):

### Bash, 286

this is a simple bash answer using the date program

```
d(){ date -d $1 +%$2; };D=$(echo $1|sed 's/\(T..\)$/\1:00/');H=$(d $D H);M=$(d $D m);if [ $(d $D u) -gt 5 ]||[ $H -lt 7 ]||[ $H -gt 18 ];then echo Off;exit;fi;if [ $M -gt 4 ]&&[ $M -lt 11 ];then I=On;O=Mid;else I=Mid;O=On;fi;if [ $H -gt 10 ]&&[ $H -lt 17 ];then echo $I;else echo $O;fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Here goes another one!

## JavaScript, <s>175</s> 171

```js
function f(x){d=new Date(x.slice(0,10));t=x.slice(11,13),m=(x.slice(5,7)+1)%12;return(t<8||t>18||!(d.getUTCDay()%6)?'off':((t<11||t>17)?(m<5?'on':'mid'):(m<5?'mid':'on'))}
```

Unminified:

```js
function f(x) {
  d = new Date(x.slice(0, 10));
  t = x.slice(11, 13), m = (x.slice(5, 7) + 1) % 12;
  return (t < 8 || t > 18 || !(d.getUTCDay() % 6) ? 'off' : ((t < 11 || t > 17) ? (m < 5 ? 'on' : 'mid') : (m < 5 ? 'mid' : 'on'))
}
```

Only works on interpreters where an ISO8601 date string can be passed into the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor.

## CoffeeScript, <s>192</s> 189

Surprisingly, it's longer in CoffeeScript because there's no ternary operator in that language (which as you can see from my JavaScript, I heavily relied on).

```coffee
f=(x)->d=new Date(x.slice(0,10));t=x.slice(11,13);m=(x.slice(5,7)+1)%12;return'off'if(t<8||t>18||!(d.getUTCDay()%6));if(t<11||t>17)then(if m<5then'on'else'mid')else(if m<5then'mid'else'on')
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3 - 352 chars

```python
import datetime as dt
t=input()
i=int
p=print
a='on'
b='mid'
c='off'
m=i(t[5:7])
h=i(t[11:13])
d=dt.date(i(t[0:4]),m,i(t[8:10])).weekday()
if 5==d or 6==d:p(c)
elif h>=19 and h<7:p(c)
elif m<=10 and m>=4:
 if h>=7 and h<11:p(b)
 if h>=11 and h<17:p(a)
 if h>=17 and h<19:p(b)
else:
 if h>=7 and h<11:p(a)
 if h>=11 and h<17:p(b)
 if h>=17 and h<19:p(a)
```

Comment: You should change `s=['high','mid','off']` to `s=['on','mid','off']` - not only does this save 2 chars, but the spec says to output "on".

Answer (score 0):

### Java - <s>426</s> 309 / 301? (see comments)

```java
String z(String a){
    DateParser b=new DateParser(a);
    boolean c=b.parseEcmaDate();
    Integer[]d=b.getDateFields();
    GregorianCalendar e=new GregorianCalendar(d[0],d[1]-(c?0:1),d[2]);
    e.setTimeZone(new SimpleTimeZone(0,""));
    return(124>>e.get(7)&1)>0&d[3]>6&d[3]<19?
           d[3]>10&d[3]<17^(1008>>e.get(2)&1)>0?"Mid":"On":"Off";
}
```

Example output:

```
2014-03-02T00   Off
2014-03-02T06   Off
2014-03-02T07   Off
2014-03-02T10   Off
2014-03-02T11   Off
2014-03-02T16   Off
2014-03-02T17   Off
2014-03-02T18   Off
2014-03-02T19   Off
2014-03-02T23   Off
2014-04-02T00   Off
2014-04-02T06   Off
2014-04-02T07   On
2014-04-02T10   On
2014-04-02T11   Mid
2014-04-02T16   Mid
2014-04-02T17   On
2014-04-02T18   On
2014-04-02T19   Off
2014-04-02T23   Off
2014-05-02T00   Off
2014-05-02T06   Off
2014-05-02T07   Mid
2014-05-02T10   Mid
2014-05-02T11   On
2014-05-02T16   On
2014-05-02T17   Mid
2014-05-02T18   Mid
2014-05-02T19   Off
2014-05-02T23   Off
```

I used the same EXOR trick as the Python submission. <s>I also used a `+` as an OR function, for when it's `weekend OR night`.</s>

My other big trick: bit masks.

For example, to see if a number is between 2 and 6 (Monday to Friday), first create a bit pattern where the interesting values are 1:

```
  6   2 
0b1111100 = 124
```

Then, use bit shift to get the interesting bit to the LSB and extract it:

```
(124 >> day_of_week) & 1
```

Similarly, I made bit patterns for months and hours:

```
  9    4
0b1111110000 = 1008

      76          76
0b111110000000000001111111 = 16253055
0b000000011111100000000000 = 129024
```

Unfortunately, it turns out simply `x>y&x<z` is shorter in most cases, so I didn't use it in some places.

And finally, a bit of hackery (highly implementation dependent) with `jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.DateParser`:
When `parseEcmaDate()` doesn't completely parse a date (like when it reads hour and hits end of string), it returns false.

- When it finishes properly, the date is stored in an `Integer[]` (auto-unboxing ftw), with the month fixed to be base-0 (like other Java classes).
- When it returns false, it aborted half-way and didn't do this fixing. It however still put whatever it parsed into the array, which is readily available. Hence the `-(c?0:1)`.

Comment: I think using just `.parse()` might also work (shaving off 8 characters), but I haven't tested it thoroughly with different inputs. `parse` internally calls `parseEcmaDate` and if it fails, calls `parseLegacyDate`. The latter may screw up the array, but this didn't happen with a few cases I tested.

Answer (score 0):

## ES6 - 146

This is in function form, uses a couple nasty hacks.

```js
let y,m,d,h,c=s=>[y,m,d,h]=s.split(/[T:-]/g).map(i=>+i),new Date(y,m,d).getDay()in{0:1,6:1}||h<20||8>h?'Off':['Mid','On'][(10>h&&h>16)^(m>5||m<8)]
```

Explained:

```js
// These variables are declared outside of the function scope to save
// characters.
let y, // year
    m, // month
    d, // day
    h, // hour
    c = s => // c for check, called as c(isoString)
      [y, m, d, h] = // Assign to fields
        s.split(/[T:-]/g) // Split at delimiters
         .map(i => +i), // Convert all to numbers
                        // Comma used to keep it as a single statement.
      new Date(y, m, d).getDay() // Create Date to get day of week
        in {0:1, 6:1} // Check if it is good (0 = Sunday, 6 = Saturday). It
                      // is shorter to use an object literal than to
                      // do individual checks.
      ||
      h < 20 || 8 > h ? // h is between 7 and 19 (7pm)
       'Off' : // Return 'Off'
       ['Mid','On'][ // Two other outputs
        (10 > h && h > 16) ^ // Check if it is 11-16 (5pm)
        (m > 5 || m < 8)] // Invert that if the month is in summer/fall. Note
                          // that this returns a number, either 1 or 0. This
                          // is an ugly hack using the bitwise xor operator.
```

Answer (score -1):

Nothing stops me from entering my own, and there's other shorter ones here anyways, so…

## PHP 5.4+, 194

```php
<?function f($x){$t=substr($x,11,2);$m=(substr($x,5,2)+1)%12;if($t<8||$t>18||(new DateTime(substr($x,0,10)))->format('N')>5)return'off';return($t<11||$t>17)?($m<5?'on':'mid'):($m<5?'mid':'on');}
```

Unminified and commented:

```php
<?
function f($x) {
  $t = substr($x,11,2); // hour
  $m = (substr($x,5,2) + 1) % 12; // month shifted up by 1

  if ($t < 8 || $t > 18 || (new DateTime(substr($x,0,10)))->format('N') > 5)
    return 'off'; // evenings and weekends

  return ($t < 11 || $t > 17)
    ? ($m < 5 ? 'on' : 'mid') // morning and mid-afternoon
    : ($m < 5 ? 'mid' : 'on'); // afternoon
}
```

Also note that the `date.timezone` directive in php.ini must be set, otherwise an Exception will be thrown.